# How I change the dir from LTR to RTL in ionic 4 programmatically

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working on ionic 4 multi-language app English and Arabic so I need when the user switching between langs the layout change!

I was doing this in ionic 3 by `platform.setDir('rtl')` at `onChangLang` event

```
    if (languageId === 'ar') {
      this.platform.setDir('rtl', true);
      this.translate.setDefaultLang(languageId);

    } else {
      this.platform.setDir('ltr', true);
      this.translate.setDefaultLang(languageId);
    }
```

**But** now in ionic 4 `platform.setDir()` has been deprecated ( removed ) for whatever reasons and the documentation doesn't include any replacement for `platform.setDir()` or how to change the `dir` programmatically!!

**So my Question is how to change the layout direction programmatically using typescript like it was on ionic 3?!!**

Comment: cant you use two separate CSS file for English and Arabic

Comment: Not an efficient solution a lot of RTL issues/conflicts happened when trying doing this! 

like the solution down there using JS Dom `document.documentElement.dir = 'rtl';`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `document.documentElement.dir = "rtl";`

```
if (languageId === 'ar') {
  document.documentElement.dir = "rtl";
  this.translate.setDefaultLang(languageId);

} else {
  document.documentElement.dir = "ltr";
  this.translate.setDefaultLang(languageId);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54932544/1483851) -- it worked for me.  The author references a Mozilla/MDN [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document), and creates an Angular Service to reference the DOCUMENT and flip from 'ltr' to 'rtl'.  Rather than copy that answer take a look at the links included in this post