# Ionic 4 with Angular how to set dynamic HTML dir attribute?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to detect the translation file of the user and based on it, to get the required direction. For example, HE will get RTL, EN will get LTR.

However I don't find a way to implement the data in the `<html dir="">` tag

This is the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps (remove if not needed) -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));
    }
  </script>-->

  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
       It contains all of the dependencies in node_modules -->
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

  <!-- The main bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Config, Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Title } from "@angular/platform-browser";

import { FirstRunPage } from '../pages';
import { Settings } from '../providers';

@Component({
  templateUrl: "app.component.html"
})
export class MyApp {

  rootPage = FirstRunPage;

  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  pages: any[] = [
    { title: 'Tutorial', component: 'TutorialPage' },
    { title: 'Welcome', component: 'WelcomePage' },
    { title: 'Tabs', component: 'TabsPage' },
    { title: 'Cards', component: 'CardsPage' },
    { title: 'Content', component: 'ContentPage' },
    { title: 'Login', component: 'LoginPage' },
    { title: 'Signup', component: 'SignupPage' },
    { title: 'Master Detail', component: 'ListMasterPage' },
    { title: 'Menu', component: 'MenuPage' },
    { title: 'Settings', component: 'SettingsPage' },
    { title: 'Search', component: 'SearchPage' }
  ]

  constructor(private titleService:Title, private translate: TranslateService, platform: Platform, settings: Settings, private config: Config, private statusBar: StatusBar, private splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    this.titleService.setTitle("Some title");
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
    this.initTranslate();
  }

  initTranslate() {
    // Set the default language for translation strings, and the current language.
    this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
    this.translate.use(this.translate.getBrowserLang() || 'en');

    this.translate.get(['BACK_BUTTON_TEXT']).subscribe(values => {
      this.config.set('ios', 'backButtonText', values.BACK_BUTTON_TEXT);
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }
}
```

As you can see I don't have "scope" in the index.html file, only under the router outlet. How can I make custom changes in the index.html page?

Answer (score 10):

You cannot and should not try to put the html tags into angular components, at best it will cause trouble.

You would have to grab the instance of the browser document object by injecting it like this, e.g. in your app component:

https://angular.io/api/common/DOCUMENT

And set the `dir` attribute:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private doc) {}

  setDir(dir: string) {
    this.doc.dir = dir;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setDir('rtl')
  }
}
```

Probably this is best put into a separate service so you can clearly define how to interact with the `document`

**Document Service**

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {DOCUMENT} from '@angular/common';

type ReadingDirection = 'ltr' | 'rtl';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class DocumentService {

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private doc) {}

  public setReadingDirection(dir: ReadingDirection) {
    this.doc.dir = dir;
  }
}
```

**App Component**

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DocumentService } from './document.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private documentService: DocumentService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.documentService.setReadingDirection('rtl')
  }

}
```

Demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p8riqb

Comment: very well written answer!

Comment: Please note you will have to kill the cache and reload the data you already shown the user, because even if you use `flip-rtl` in your icons, those that were already loaded will remain like they are - and the menu as well won't open from the good side. I would recommend redirecting the user to the root of your app after applying the new dir : `this.navCtlr.navigateRoot('', {animationDirection: 'back'});`

Comment: Best answer so far.. it work perfectly

Comment: Would still be nice to be accepted :D